# run java class in octave

Tags: java, octave

I'm trying to call java object in Octave. For example, here's my java code (square class):

```
public class square {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public square(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double s()
    {
        return x*y;
    }
}
```

And my main class:

```
public class console {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        square kv = new square(3, 4);
        double r = kv.s();
        System.out.println("result: " + r);
    }
}
```

How can i call square class or console class in Octave? I've tried following which didn't work.
I tried to create `javaclasspath` like `javaaddpath("C:\Users\User\Desktop\javaTest\console.jar")`. I also add in `javaclasspath.txt` paths such as `~\console.class, ~\console.java` and so on.

In octave i tried to call object like `obj = javaObject("console")`  but i always get an error

```
error: [java] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: console
```

Ofcourse i tried with various "console" parameters like "console.class", "console.java", "square", ...

Comment: try `so = javaObject ("square", 5, 5); so.s ()`

Comment: I tired i get same error `ClassNotFoundException`.  I assume that octave does not see my .jar files or classes

Comment: It should see. Make sure they are on the static javaclasspath (add the path to the jar file --- the path for the file, not the path for the directory where the file is --- to the javaclasspath.txt file). After you start Octave, check that it correct by calling `javaclasspath`; it should display a table with the jar file under "static java path".

Comment: Ok, i'll try. One note, where octave looks for javaclasspath.txt file? I have placed file in installation folder of octave, in user home folder but octave does not see it.

Comment: Ok, i found a solution. I had to navigate path to `"...\console\bin"` and then call it like `obj = javaObject("package.console")` and now it works. Thanks for help.